# How does Implicit Quantile-Regression Network (IQN) differ from QR-DQN?

Tags: regression, reinforcement-learning, dqn

For several months I browsed the internet hoping to find a user-friendly explanation of the [Implicit Quantile Regression Network (IQN)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.06923.pdf). But, it seems there is none at all.

**How does [IQN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.06923.pdf) differ from [Quantile Regression Network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.10044.pdf), in plain language?**

In Reinforcement Learning, a **DQN** would simply output a Q-value for each action. This allows for Temporal Difference learning: linearly interpolating the current estimate of Q-value (of the currently chosen action) towards Q' - the value of the best action from the next state.

**[Quantile-Regression Network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.10044.pdf)** takes it a step further, outputting a range of values for each action. So if with DQN we had a vector of Q values, QR-DQN gives us a vector of sub-vectors of Q values. These Q-values are *equally likely to occur* when compared amongst each other (in that sub-vector).

For example, if we have 3 possible actions, QR-Network might output the following:

```
Q estimates for Action0:  -15,  -5,  120,  121   130    
Q estimates for Action1:   20,  25,  200,  210   300
Q estimates for Action2:   18,  40,   41,   54   120
```

Once again, when working with QR-Network, we treat `-15,  -5,  120,  121,  130`  as having the same probability of occurring: in my case  0.2  or 20%

In other words, each action now has values sitting at the middles of 5 separate quantiles:  at $\tau$ = 0.1, $\tau$=0.3, $\tau$=0.5, $\tau$=0.7, $\tau$=0.9

We can therefore say, that for the Action0:

- with probability of 20% values within [$-\infty$, -10] will occur
- with probability of 40% values within [$-\infty$, 57.5] will occur
- with probability of 60% values within [$-\infty$, 120.5] will occur
- with probability of 80% values within [$-\infty$, 121.5] will occur
- with probability of 100% values within [$-\infty$, $+\infty$] will occur

To conclude, with QR-Net we demand it to output correct sub-vectors, knowing that each Q-score must have the same probability as others in that sub-vector.

**Now, how does IQN work?**

From what I understood after checking the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.06923.pdf), we have to feed the network the $\tau$ itself (in my example either 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7 or 0.9),

Or should we instead feed it several random $\tau$, pulled from [0,1] range? 
Say, we pulled-out `0.35,  0.05,  0.1,  0.2,  0.11,` should we continue getting them, or should we stop once we taken out 5 of those $\tau$ values? Would that mean we have to do a forward-pass for every $\tau$ or can we use a vector of them all, at once?

As I understood, we have to feed this $\tau$ as an input, into the network, along with the state vector (concatenating).

Does IQN output only 1 value per action, or a vector of vectors, like QR-Network does?

The IQN paper gives a picture, but I am unable to grasp the intuition behind the 4th image:

[image]

Why does the above image show the $f$ function being used in DQN and in IQN **but not** in C51 or QR-DQN?  Does that mean that the output is no longer a vector of vectors, but is just a vector, like in a usual DQN?

The gist of IQN is in the following paragraph, but I just can't grasp it fully. What's the intuition behind the cosine? I know it's a periodical function, why does it get computed 64 times with i=0 to i=64, with the same $\tau$ (for example $\tau=0.4$ etc)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Would like to thank Will Dabney and Georg Ostrovski (two of the paper's several authors),  and Massimiliano Tomassoli ([Simple-Machine-Learning blog](https://mtomassoli.github.io/about/) owner) for helping me understand IQN.

To understand this algorithm, you will need to know:

- TD Learning
- Value Functions of Reinforcement Learning
- What a DQN is.
- What C51 is
- What a Cummulative Distribution Function is (CDF)
- What an Inverse CDF is.

Just like C51 or QR-DQN, IQN allows us to estimate an entire distribution of possible rewards if we take some action $a$.  However, IQN doesn't output a distribution like those did.  Instead, it outputs a single sample every time you ask it. It outputs that red dot you see on the right, of the bottom image.

The final output of IQN is 1 scalar value per action. In other words, just a single sample per action.  We re-run IQN several times to get more samples for the "CurrentState".

IQN takes input at 2 different stages: 1)  and 2)

1. First, the IQN takes a current state S (which is a vector), transforms it into another vector **V** (for example, of dimension 10).
2. now, we take any random scalar value called $\tau$ (drawn from a uniform [0,1] range), and feed that scalar value into function $\phi(\tau)$.  It gives us a vector **H**,  which has the same dimension as **V**
3. then, vectors **V** and **H** get combined via concatenation. In fact, we perform multiplication instead of concatenation if there won't be many forward layers further on.
4. At the end of this forward-pass, our IQN outputs an |A| dimensional vector,  containing samples of the action-distributions we are trying to estimate. |A| is the other way to say the "number of actions". Notice: because IQN outputs a vector, and not a matrix (like QR-DQN does), we only get 1 scalar sample per action when performing a forward pass from the current State.
5. To get more samples, we have to return back to step 2)  and re-run the forward pass with some another scalar $\tau$  once again sampled from [0,1] range. Or, of course, we can re-use our IQN, to run the needed number of such forward-passes in parallel, if hardware allows. No need to start all the way from step 1) because we only care about the end-layers where $\tau$ actually enters the system. "Any preceding layers" would be re-computed to the same values anyway.

When training, we evaluate "CurrentState+1" as well. We bootstrap our results from "CurrentState" towards "CurrentState+1" via usual TD-learning, just like a usual DQN would do.  Don't forget, we will have to re-run forward pass several times (as step 5. has mentioned) both for "CurrentState" and for "CurrentState+1" to get several samples of the current and target distributions. This gives us a fairly good idea about what those two distributions look like.

6. According to the paper, in most cases re-running the forward pass 8 times (thus getting 8 samples) suffices for approximating both the $Z_{\tau}$ and our target distribution $Z$ (the distribution of the best action for "CurrState+1").  So we perform 16 forward passes in total:  8 for  "CurrentState"  and 8 for "CurrentState+1" to get an idea about those two distributions.

---

Why does feeding a random $\tau$ into the network work?

You have to understand that a well-trained IQN network represents an Inverse CDF itself.  That is, given a request of some scalar 'amount' value (taken from a uniform range of 0 to 1), the Inverse CDF will output a value from the actual distribution, that sits at that amount.

Although distributions won't necessarily look like Bell-curves, have a look at this example:

[image]

---

Why do authors use cosine inside $\phi(\tau)$ ?  I still have no idea, but the Appendix section of the paper states it seems to work the best. Perhaps it works good with ReLU.

[image]

---

I also got confused by $w_{ij}$ or $b_j$. To me it seemed there is a matrix of weights and a vector of bias values. ...Do we input an entire vector of different $\tau$ values at once?

The answer is no. Notice, authors used $j$ only to remind that forward pass has to run several times. 
In total, there is only i number of weights in $\phi(\tau)$ and 1 bias.

Therefore, we get some scalar $\tau$, and use it with all those weights.  Basically $\phi(\tau)$ resembles a simple fully-connected layer, which only accept 1 scalar input value at a time.  We will re-use this same layer for different $\tau$ scalar values.

Comment: Any updates on this or other information you'd like to share?  Months later and still not that much information out there from what I can tell.

Comment: @Kari Nice post! However, the last section about intuition on Equation 4 is incorrect. Since the description is quite long, I post it as [another answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/72109/47237) with an ugly hand-drawn illustration.

Answer (score 4):

[Kari](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/43077/kari)'s answer is concise and very informative. However, the explanation for Equation 4 is slightly incorrect. (final section of the post)

$$\phi_j(\tau):=\text{ReLU}(\sum\limits^{n-1}_{i=0}\cos(\pi i\tau)w_{ij}+b_j)$$

$w_{ij}$ is indeed a matrix and $b_j$ is a vector.

It's better to interpret the equation by layers:

[image: layers]

Let's say we have a single $\tau$, and we want to perform a single forward pass to get its value $Z_\tau(x_t,a_t)$.

- Input ($\tau$, $|\tau|=1$)

  We have a scalar $\tau$.

  $$\tau\sim U([0,1])$$
- Intermediate result ($I_i$, $|I|=n=64$)

  Expand the scalar $\tau$ to a vector by $\cos(\pi i\tau)$ for $i\in[0,n-1]$.

  $$I_i=\cos(\pi i\tau)$$

  The number 64 is used in the paper.
- Embedding of current $\tau$ ($\phi_j$, $|\phi|=256$)

  Use fully connected layer to expand $I$ to $\phi$ with $|W|=i\cdot j$ and $|b|=j$.

  $$\phi_j(\tau):=\text{ReLU}(\sum\limits^{n-1}_{i=0}I_i w_{ij}+b_j)$$

  The number 256 is the number of neurons of the layer after convolutions in DQN architecture.
- Then we conduct element-wise multiplication $\psi\odot\phi$ and continues pass it into DQN's last layer.

For multiple passes, we can simply treat all $\tau$ as a batch and run the forward pass in parallel.

The concept above is Universal Value Function Approximator (UVFA), while the cosine term is chosen since it results in good empirical results.